# Fullpage.js Slider auto scrolls up to top of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

***(I'm New to CSS transitions)***

So I have a simple fullpage.js slider, after every slide change it automatically scrolls to the very top of the page. It might be because of a transition property in its css file. I've tried to finding the property but to no luck.

**Problem:** **Not 100% sure why it just scrolls to the top but I think it might be something in its `javascript.fullpage.css` that is causing the issue?**

Or am I missing something? Please help!

NOTE: the html is only part of my own html structure. Is that the reason why??

HTML

```
    <section class="work-wrapper">

        <h2>OUR WORK</h2>
        <div id="work-flex-wrap">
            <div class="work-content">
                <h3>CASE STUDY: INTITUTE OF PROFESSIONAL EXCELLENCE </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="slide-wrapper">
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <?php get_sidebar('portfolio-showcase') ?>              
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

</section>
```

CSS

```
    /**
 * fullPage Pure Javascript v.0.0.9 (Alpha) - Not support given until Beta version.
 * https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js
 * MIT licensed
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2013 alvarotrigo.com - A project by Alvaro Trigo
 */
html.fp-enabled,
.fp-enabled body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;

    /*Avoid flicker on slides transitions for mobile phones #336 */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
#superContainer {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;

    /* Touch detection for Windows 8 */
    -ms-touch-action: none;

    /* IE 11 on Windows Phone 8.1*/
    touch-action: none;
}
.fp-section {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari<=5 Android<=3 */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* <=28 */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100%;
}
.fp-slide {
    float: left;
}
.fp-slide, .fp-slidesContainer {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.fp-slides {
    z-index:1;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; /* Safari<=6 Android<=4.3 */
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.fp-section.fp-table, .fp-slide.fp-table {
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
.fp-tableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.fp-slidesContainer {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.fp-controlArrow {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: -38px;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev {
    left: 15px;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 38.5px 34px 38.5px 0;
    border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-next {
    right: 15px;
    border-width: 38.5px 0 38.5px 34px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
}
.fp-scrollable {
    overflow: scroll;

}
.fp-notransition {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
#fp-nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-top: -32px;
    top: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
}
#fp-nav.right {
    right: 17px;
}
#fp-nav.left {
    left: 17px;
}
.fp-slidesNav{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.fp-slidesNav.bottom {
    bottom: 17px;
}
.fp-slidesNav.top {
    top: 17px;
}
#fp-nav ul,
.fp-slidesNav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#fp-nav ul li,
.fp-slidesNav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 7px;
    position:relative;
}
.fp-slidesNav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#fp-nav ul li a,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#fp-nav ul li a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span,
#fp-nav ul li:hover a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span{
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
#fp-nav ul li a span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a span {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 4px;
    width: 4px;
    border: 0;
    background: #333;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
#fp-nav ul li .fp-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
}
#fp-nav ul li:hover .fp-tooltip,
#fp-nav.fp-show-active a.active + .fp-tooltip{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
#fp-nav ul li .fp-tooltip.right {
    right: 20px;
}
#fp-nav ul li .fp-tooltip.left {
    left: 20px;
}
```

UPDATE:

**fullpage js script** 
**PLEASE NOTE THAT I'M USING javascript.fullpage.min.js instead of the bellow file** *(because I believe its the same code just compressed, right?)*

(using .min.js again!)
git link: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.fullpage.min.js

(uncompressed version) readable git link: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.fullpage.js

Comment: can you please share me the fullpage.js initialization script

Comment: @Mgkrish I've added it in the question. any ideas?